# Select de um argumento de uma coluna com vários argumentos

Tags: sql, columns

Bom dia, deparei-me com uma dúvida que não consigo resolver.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
select id, name, characteristics as characteristic
from monsters
order by id
```

Devolve-me a seguinte tabela:

```
id  name    characteristic
1   Cyril   big, smelly
2   Tiny    small, stinky, loud
3   Niall   flatulent
4   Umph    idiotic, nasty
5   Martin  mad, stupid, bad-breath
```

Está-me a ser pedido para devolver apenas a primeira palavra da characteristic...
Como posso resolver?

Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa primeiro localizar a primeira ocorrência da vírgula, e selecionar as characteristic até a posição onde ela se encontra. Para selecionar parte da uma string, você pode utilizar a funçao subtring, para localizar a primeira ocorrência de um determinado caractere você pode utilizar a função charindex. Aqui tem um exemplo:

```
select id, name, substring(characteristics,1,charindex(',',characteristics,1)-1) as characteristic
from monsters
order by id
```

Outra forma mais simples de chegar no mesmo resultado seria utilizar a função LEFT. Aqui tem um exemplo com MySQL

```
select id, name, LEFT(characteristics,LOCATE(' ',characteristics) - 1) as characteristic
from monsters
order by id
SELECT
```

Comment: Eu diria , normalize o modelo https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados